# Neither JsonOutput.toJson or writeJSON is producing strings with quotes(JSON)

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to convert a map in jenkinsfile to json for which I'm using

```
def pullRequestData = [
        title: "Deployment-to-SIT",
        description: "Pull request from",
        state: "OPEN",
        open: "true",
        closed: "false",
        fromRef: [
            id: "refs/heads/${branchjsonObj.displayId}",
            repository: [
                slug: "${reposlug}",
                name: "null",
                project: [
                    key: "${projectkey}"
                ]
            ]
        ]
]
def jsonmap = JsonOutput.toJson(pullRequestData)
echo ${jsonmap}
```

gives the output as json formatted but without strings like,

> {title:Deployment-to-SIT,description:Pull request from,state:OPEN,open:true,closed:false,fromRef:{id:refs/heads/deployment-to-SIT,repository:{slug:argocd-sample-chart,name:null,project:{key:TD}}}}

but the output i need is

> {"title":"Deployment-to-SIT","description":"Pull request from","state":"OPEN","open":"true","closed":"false","fromRef":{"id":"refs/heads/deployment-to-SIT","repository":{"slug":"argocd-sample-chart","name":"null","project":{"key":"TD"}}}

Also tried,

```
def jsonpullRequestData = this.steps.writeJSON(file: 'jsonmap.json', json: pullRequestData)
```

But the behavior is same,o/p is without quotes.Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: this is incorrect json: `{ "a" : "b",{"c" : "d"}}`. and this is incorrect code: `def map = [a : "b",[c : "d"]]`. probably it's a bug that jenking allows you this code, but in groovy it's wrong code.

Comment: @daggett Please check the question now and let me know if its incorect

Comment: I don't see from your code what is the value of the map parameter and where do you take it. Actually both variants should produce correct json. So, question in what you are passing into those variants.

Comment: @daggett appreciate your response,please see the question updated now

Comment: It should be `echo jsonmap`. And could you add a screenshot of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using json groovy lib.. as per your requirement you can directly use `$pullRequestData`.toString() method to get in string format with quotes.

Comment: But for that i cannot define my data as map,I need JSON as output.